# jQuery: detach and re-attach element without reloading content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if it's possible using jQuery to detach and then re-attach an element (e.g. a div) to the DOM without reloading the content within the element.

Consider this example layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="something.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="something.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <iframe src="example.com" id="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card">
            <!-- User hides this card -->
            <img src="something.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <iframe src="example.com" id="widget">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are 3 cards in the first column and two in the second column. If the user hides one of the cards in the second column, I want to restack the cards by moving one of the cards from the first column to the second column, so that there are now two cards in each column. I can accomplish this using `.detach()` and `.appendTo()` easily enough, but when I re-attach the card from the first column to the second, whatever content that card contains is reloaded, be it an image or a widget such as an embedded Tweet.

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to move a card from one column to another without triggering the content within it to be reloaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `.clone()` does not appear to request resource again. Note, `.detach()` is called after `.appendTo()` .

Note also that `id` of element with a `document` should be unique; two elements having `id` `"widget"` are within `html` at Question; try changing to `class="widget"`

```js
$(".col-lg-6:eq(1) div").click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).hide();
  var clone = $(".col-lg-6:eq(0) div:eq(0)").clone();  
  clone.appendTo(".col-lg-6:eq(1)");
  $(".col-lg-6:eq(0) div:first").detach();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature" />
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats" />
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <iframe src="example.com" class="widget"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card">
            <!-- User hides this card -->
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports" />
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <iframe src="example.com" class="widget"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! `.clone()` seems to work for me without reloading the image. For what it's worth I couldn't get your example to work, but when I toyed around in the console with a layout I'm working on, I was able to move cards around without reloading images or embedded widgets.