# jQuery appendTo() without reloading embedded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I've written a stacking function with jQuery that takes container element `.search-results`, gathers all the `.card` elements within each `.col` element in the container and then restacks them across a number of columns, which are calculated based off the width of the container.

When the page is loaded, all cards are initialized in the first column and subsequent columns are hidden. The script then unhides however many columns it determines should exist and iterates through the columns and cards, using `appendTo` to evenly distribute the cards amongst the columns.

I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ufgbn48/7/) that demonstrates the process.

The script works great when it's called on page load. If I want to call the script after the page has loaded though, I encounter a serious problem. If I remove one of the cards and want to restack them so the distribution remains even, I must call the stacking function again. When I do so, it causes the embedded content (e.g. embedded Tweets) within the cards to be reloaded, which is undesirable. Note that when the page loads the Tweets are not initialized until after the stacking function has been called.

In my example I intentionally iterate over the tweet ids to reinitialize them using `twttr.widgets.createTweet()`, however if I omit that step, the Tweets disappear after the cards are restacked. If I inspect the cards I can see that the Tweet widget iframe is still present, but the iframe's `body` is empty.

Now obviously I could simply reinitialize my Tweets after I restack the cards but that would offer up a poor user experience since there is a delay when (re)initializing an embedded Tweet. I had previously posed a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734634/jquery-detach-and-re-attach-element-without-reloading-content) related to this. I found that I can manually move cards around from the console using `.clone()` and `appendTo()` *without* reloading the embedded Tweets, however I've not had any luck refactoring my stacking function to take advantage of this behavior, which is why I'm asking this question.

Here is my stacking function:

```
function resizeColumns(layoutElem, ignoreRank, width) {
    if (width === undefined) {
        var colMin = 300;
    } else {
        var colMin = width;
    }

    var w = layoutElem.width();
    var numCols = Math.floor(w / colMin);
    if (numCols === 0) numCols = 1;

    layoutElem.removeClass('cols-1 cols-2 cols-3 cols-4 cols-5 cols-6 cols-7 cols-8 cols-9 cols-10 cols-11 cols-12');
    layoutElem.addClass('cols-' + numCols);
    var cols = layoutElem.find('.col');
    var cards = cols.find('.card');
    var sortedCards = [];
    cards.each(function(i) {
        var rank;
        if (!ignoreRank) {
            rank = parseInt($(this).attr('rank'));
            if (isNaN(rank)) rank = 1000000;
        } else {
            var o = parseInt($(this).attr('order'));
            if (isNaN(o)) {
                rank = i;
                $(this).attr('order', i);
            } else {
                rank = o;
            }
        }
        sortedCards.push({
            rank: rank,
            element: $(this)
        });
    });
    sortedCards.sort(rankCompare);
    var curCol = 0;
    for (var i in sortedCards) {
        var cardElem = sortedCards[i].element;
        cardElem.appendTo($(cols[curCol]));
        curCol++;
        if (curCol >= numCols) curCol = 0;
    }
    // hide any additional columns
    cols.each(function(i) {
        if (i >= numCols) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });

    function rankCompare(a, b) {
        if (a.rank < b.rank)
        return -1;
        if (a.rank > b.rank)
        return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Steps I take to stack the cards and initialize the Tweets in the jsFiddle**

The first time I call the function I introduce a delay so that `$scope.cards` is defined. Here is the first call:

```
$timeout(function() {
    // Only the first argument is required.
    resizeColumns($('.cards'), true, 250);
}, 250)
```

After I call the `resizeColumns` function I set a delay before initializing the tweets for the first time. This is essential so that the Twitter widgets script can locate the Tweets in the DOM.

Once the Tweets are initialized, I set a delay of 4s before removing a card and restacking the cards. Finally, once the cards are restacked, I reinitialize the Tweets. This last step is what I want to avoid. I don't want to have to reinitialize the Tweets because it's a slow process. I want the Tweet to reappear instantly once the card is moved.

```
$timeout(function() {
    // Iterate over the Tweet IDs and initialize them.
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
        twttr.widgets.createTweet(id, document.getElementById(id));
    });

    $timeout(function() {
        // Wait a few seconds and then remove a card from the DOM.
        $('#' + $scope.cards[1].id).detach();
        // Restack cards
        resizeColumns($('.cards'), true, 250);
        $timeout(function() {
            // Reinitialize Tweets after cards have been restacked. This is the step I want to avoid.
            ids.forEach(function(id) {
                twttr.widgets.createTweet(id, document.getElementById(id));
            });
        }, 500)
    }, 4000);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to the other question, try changing:

```
    sortedCards.push({
        rank: rank,
        element: $(this)
    });
```

to:

```
    sortedCards.push({
        rank: rank,
        element: $(this).clone();
    });
    $(this).detach();
```

Or you could do the clone and detach in the `appendTo` loop:

```
for (var i in sortedCards) {
    var cardElem = sortedCards[i].element.clone();
    cardElem.appendTo($(cols[curCol]));
    sortedCards[i].element.detach()
    curCol = (curCol + 1) % numCols;
}
```

Comment: I had the same ideas on how to apply `.clone()` to the function, but I couldn't get it to work. Tested on the fiddle and the Tweets still disappear after the function is called a second time. That is to say I have to reinitialize them, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I added my code to your fiddle, how do I make it call the function again?

Comment: I just updated my question with a clearer explanation of the steps I take to stack/restack the cards. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: I think the `detach()` in the timeout function is the problem. Why do you need to do that before calling `resizeColumns`?

Comment: I'm using it to simulate a user hiding one of these cards. In my actual app, the cards have a button to hide them. Doing so toggles a boolean attribute triggering the card to be removed from the DOM by an `ng-if` block attached to the card. I didn't want to try and replicate all that additional functionality in the fiddle so I just used `.detach()`. To be sure I did test your code on the actual app but the behavior was the same as in the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that the card you're detaching is not one of the ones being re-sorted.

Comment: I can't figure out why it worked in your previous question but doesn't work the same way here. Are you sure that answer really worked?

Comment: Oh, I see. This isn't about the DOM elements, it's about reinitializing the tweets. Maybe using `.clone(true)` will solve that, because it copies all the event bindings of the original element.

Comment: Tried `.clone(true)` in both spots and neither worked. Interestingly in the fiddle the Tweets load the first time but then fail to reload. In my app, the Tweets don't load at all when using `.clone()` or `.clone(true)` in the function.

Comment: I think this question has more to do with the Twitter API than DOM/jQuery.

Comment: I have no idea why I was able to do this from the console using `.clone()` before. When I did it that way it seems like the Tweets didn't reload and the buttons on the widget still worked.

Comment: I tagged `twitter` on the question. For what it's worth in my app I also have embedded Facebook posts. Their embed widget used an iframe like Twitter's and I have the same issue with those as with the Tweets.