# How to Prevent Refresh in Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

The following is the sample code.

```
<div id="ads">
    <!-- Adsense Script -->
</div>

<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
```

I move Addense to DIv A or Div B.

```
$(".A").append( $("#ads") );
$(".B").append( $("#ads") );
```

However, Adsense is reloaded when moving.

**Can I keep the content intact?**

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/35734859/2943218

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen The results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. If you want to add ads in A and B you need to initialize them for example like this:

```js
$('.A').append(`
  <ins class="adsbygoogle" 
       data-ad-client="ca-pub-123456789" 
       style="display:block"
       data-ad-format="auto">
  </ins>`);
adsbygoogle.push({});
```

Moving already initialized ads around won't work as ads displayed in iframes and when you adding it - it adds a new iframe which means a new ad request is made and new ad displayed. In addition it might be against policy as when adsbygoogle.js initializes an ad - it calculates certain parameters based on where ad is located in the page. If you move initialized ad to some other place - those parameters will be invalid.